# C# codebehind not getting hit when button clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="userRemovalUpdatePanel">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <p><label>Remove: </label>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="removeUserList" /></p>
        <br />
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="removeUserBtn" Text="Remove User" 
            onclick="removeUserBtn_Click" CssClass="buttons"  />
        <p><label for="deleteStatus">Delete status: </label></p><br />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="deleteStatusLbl" Text="" Font-Size="Medium" Width="100" ForeColor="Red" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I put a break point on the below code behind and it never gets hit. The code behind for this is:

```
protected void removeUserBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string userToDelete = removeUserList.SelectedValue;
    Business.User deleteUser = new Business.User();
    deleteStatusLbl.Text = deleteUser.DeleteUser(userToDelete);
    fillUserDropDown();
}
```

Comment: Is your code behind page referenced correctly? `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Is this the correct file?" Inherits="RequestForm._Default" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" %>`

Comment: Do you have other components that are working but just not this specific button? Can you post the information where you declare the codebehind file?

Comment: When you run in debug mode do the breakpoints appear to grey out or change with like a little (!) or other icon over them?  If so, and you mouse over that symbol, it will give more information about what is going on.

Comment: Do you have ScriptManager on the page?

Comment: @Spacemancraig - Yes it is. @TheCapn I have other components working with the codebehind file on that page. @Cortright Nothing weird with the breakpoints.

Comment: Can you post the code of the asp button?

Comment: You don't happen to have JavaScript on the page somewhere that is setting the button to return false?

Comment: @rlb.usa The code of the asp button is in the original post. @samiz - I do have javascript on the page but nothing that is causing the button to return a value. @can pyrazoglu - I have a script manager on the page.

Comment: Does the page postback when  you hit the button?

Comment: just comment all the code from aspx except the button and then check whether button click is working

Comment: Try temporarily removing the update panel.  If there is an error it can be hidden by the update panel.

Comment: @engil - the page doesn't postback completely (partial postback because of the update panel). @latr0dectus - I will try that next, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @latr0dectus - I tried re-adding the control and still didn't help.

Comment: Do you have any validators on the page?  Also place the Application_Error event in your Global.asax and try to log any errors that take place

Comment: @latr0dectus - I had a requiredfieldvalidator. This was the problem. Once I removed it... everything is good to go. Please post that as the answer so that I can give you credit for it, and thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any validators on the page? Also place the Application_Error event in your Global.asax and try to log any errors that take place.

Validators can prevent the postback and behave strangely with update panels sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

It's not: onclick="removeUserBtn_Click"

It is: **OnClick**="removeUserBtn_Click"

Comment: Nice catch, but I changed that and it didn't work. I'm re-adding the controls now to see if that worked

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any code running in `Page_Load()`?

Code here runs *before* any event handlers are fired, so if something was interrupting your page loading here, say redirecting to another page etc. the click handler would never be fired.

The page lifecycle is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

`Page_PreRender()` is an alternative place to put code that you want to run *after* the event handlers fire.